# Making pairs out of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
function makePairs(obj) {
  var key = Object.keys(obj);
  var value = Object.values(obj);
  var result = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
      result += key[i] + '=' + value[j];
    }
  }

  return result;
  //how would I make pairs out of the object?
}

var result = makePairs({
  a: "b",
  nums: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
});

console.log(result);
```

please help.

i am trying to make one string, it should return something like "a=b,nums=1,nums=2,nums=3,nums=4,nums=5"

Comment: Are you trying to create a string or an array of strings (plural)?

Comment: am trying to make a string out of the pairs from object,something like "a=b,nums=1,nums=2,nums=3,nums=4" one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get entries of [key, value], and then iterate the entries with `Array.flatMap()`. If the `value` is an array, map it to an array of "pairs". If not just combine it a "pair". Join the resulting array to a string:

```js
const makePairs = obj => Object.entries(obj)
  .flatMap(([key, value]) => 
    Array.isArray(value) ? value.map(v => `${key}=${v}`) : `${key}=${value}`
  )
  .join(', ');

var result = makePairs({
  a: "b",
  nums: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
});

console.log(result);
```

The problem with your solution is that you are combining all keys with all values. Iterate the keys, get the values for that key, and then combine the values with the key.

In addition, it's easier to push each combination into an array, and join at the end than string concatenation. Creating a string outright would require you to identify the when and when not to add a comma, while join just adds a comma between the items.

```js
function makePairs(obj) {
  var key = Object.keys(obj);
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    var k = key[i];
    var value = Array.isArray(obj[k]) ? obj[k] : [obj[k]];
    
    for (var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
      result.push(k + '=' + value[j]);
    }
  }

  return result.join(', ');
}

var result = makePairs({
  a: "b",
  nums: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: flatMap and map are two different methods?

Comment: Yep. A flatMap will flatten an array of arrays to a one dimensional array. It only handles one level, so an array with 3 levels would be flattened to 2.

Comment: so the array.isArray is checking if there is an array in the object? so if true it returns the [1,2,3,4,5] part?

Comment: If it's an array, we need to map it further to create the pairs. If not, just create a single pair.